# For how long will a browser remember to look for serviceworker.js?

Tags: service-worker

Long story short: I have a website that used to have a service worker. I removed it. All is working well. Fine.

However, checking nginx error logs I can see how many returning visitors' browsers are checking for serviceworker.js file (probably trying to refresh the file). Since the file is no more, this makes a line in the error log saying how the resource serviceworker.js was not found.

So, is this a problem? How long will their browsers do this?
Can I "tell" any visiting browser that serviceworker.js is no more so purge any old references you have that make your browser shoot the question.

Comment: Sounds like what `410 Gone` is for. No idea whether that actually works with service workers.

Comment: @melpomene well, maybe so but it feels like a hack. Having big regrets ever trying service workers now with the headache they can cause. I guess eventually old visitors will clear their history or change computer etc so eventually - way down the road - the problem will take care of itself. Would've preferred an official "how to let the world know that your site is no longer using service workers and old service workers can be uninstalled and stop calling the site for serviceworker.js"